# Send an Email with Button Click in cms page magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, module

I was confused how to do it. Need to send all the details on the admin's email from a custom cms page where the form fields can be added/edited. After clicking submit button the form details will be sent to my email id. IS IT POSSIBLE TO DO CMS PAGE IN MAGENTO?????? Please help me urgent

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

Magento already has a page with contact form set up on `example.com/contacts/` so the easiest thing would be to edit that existing page.

You'll probably want to edit `layout/contacts.xml` or `contacts/form.phtml`

Another option would be to insert following code in your CMS page content:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Side effect of this method is that you will be redirected to `/contacts/` upon form submit.

Third option is to create your custom controller and inherit logic from `Mage_Contacts_IndexController`

Comment: Thanks for the replay. But the forms that I want to create from a CMS Block has custom attributes. And I have to add 5 such custom forms into the magento website. Can we achieve this some other way??? Like creating a module or anything else...

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question...Yes you have to create a custom module to do that.

Comment: Can you please suggest that..I havent done any kind of custom module creation in magento before.. so didnt exactly know where to start from..